# Combine two different tables Without Duplicating using Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, join, union

I am working on a query where I should combine 2 tables and get each user as a separate entry (The user should not be duplicate). For the date, I need to get the latest out of those 2 tables

**table 1**

[image]

**table 2**

[image]

**Expected output** ( I need to combine both tables and get the data's of the user as a single entry and for the date, i need to get the latest date out of those 2 tables)

```
user_id      name        date     
----------------------------------
     1       John     2020-10-29 --The latest date-- 
     2       Tom      2020-11-15 --The latest date--   
     3       Peter    2020-12-10 --The latest date--
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

**My postgresql**

```
SELECT user_id, name, date
FROM
  table_1
UNION
SELECT user_id, name, date
FROM
table_2
```

I tried many ways but nothing worked. The datas are duplicating when doing the union. Can someone help me

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combine two tables using UNION ALL then apply ROW_NUMBER() for serializing user_id wise value with descending date. Then retrieve last record by using CTE. Using UNION ALL for avoiding extra ordering.

```
-- PostgreSQL
WITH c_cte AS (
    SELECT t.*
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.user_id ORDER BY t.date DESC) row_num
    FROM (SELECT user_id, name, date
          FROM table_1

          UNION ALL

          SELECT user_id, name, date
          FROM table_2) t
)
SELECT user_id, name, date
FROM c_cte
WHERE row_num = 1
ORDER BY user_id
```

Also another way for doing same thing without CTE

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.date
FROM (SELECT t.*
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.user_id ORDER BY t.date DESC) row_num
      FROM (SELECT user_id, name, date
            FROM table_1

            UNION ALL

            SELECT user_id, name, date
            FROM table_2) t
           ) u
WHERE u.row_num = 1
ORDER BY u.user_id
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you so much.